# Do I need to use a sum in mysql or another method using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have a query I need to run in php on my mysql database and just wondering the best way to do it...

I need to add together all the quantities of the product options and use that to get a total for the product quantity.

---

Table product.

In the product table each product has a 'product_id'.
Each product contains a column 'quantity' which in most cases is inaccurate.

```
+-----------+------------+
| ProductID |  Quantity  |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | 3          |
|         2 | 5          |
|         3 | 1          | 
|         4 | 1          | 
|         5 | 4          |
|         6 | 8          |
|         7 | 2          |
+-----------+------------+
```

Table product_option_value.

In the product_option_value table each option uses the 'product_id' and contains a column 'quantity' for each option.

```
+-------------------------+------------+---------------+
| product_option_value_id | product_id |    quanity    |
+-------------------------+------------+---------------+
|            200          |      1     |      12       |
|            200          |      1     |      11       |
|            200          |      1     |      44       |
|            200          |      1     |       4       |
|            204          |      3     |       3       |
|            204          |      3     |       7       |
|            204          |      3     |       9       |
+-------------------------+------------+---------------+
```

I need to update the 'product' table 'quantity' column with the correct quantities from the 'product_option_value' table with the sum of all the 'quantity' columns where the product_id is the same as the product's product_id.

---

I was thinking making a sum of all the quantities under the option table and using them to update the product table quantity value but I'm not sure the best way to do this using php in mysql?

Comment: Usually when all you are doing is data manipulation (no logic) its best to do it in the DB. If you need to do validation or some other form of complex logic then use PHP. In this case i would use SQL only

Comment: Thankyou for the advice cernunnos, I used a mysql query without any extra php and it worked great with a sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Product
SET Product.Quantity=(
SELECT SUM(product_option_value.Quantity)
FROM product_option_value
WHERE product_option_value.product_id=Product.ProductID
)
```

Comment: Thankyou Hanky, I thought it'd be straight forward but I have never ran a sum query and I wasn't sure whether it was appropriate for this...

Comment: So I had to add an underscore and change a few of the uppercase letters then it worked!! Really appreciate the help :-) I am learning bit by bit...

Comment: Hanky just one thing in some cases a product doesn't have any options i dont want the product quantity to update, is there a way to give a condition in the mysql query or will it be a condition in php?

Comment: To do that you would need to do a JOIN in the UPDATE part of the statement. As there would be no matching record when there is no product option no record would be returned by an INNER JOIN, hence no update would occur. This is pretty much how my suggestion works.

Answer (score 0):

Within the UPDATE do a JOIN on the table with a subselect for the SUM:-

```
UPDATE Product a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, SUM(Quantity) AS SummedQty
FROM product_option_value GROUP BY product_id) b
ON b.product_id = a.ProductID
SET a.Quantity = SummedQty
```